# JavaFX addListener not working

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I'm quite a newbie on JavaFX and I need to bind the visible property of a `Label` in a way that, if the value it represents reaches 0, the `Label` should be invisible. Also, it needs to be updated when the bounded `integerProperty` value changes.

*This is my code:*

```
@FXML
private Label kingRewardLabel;

// many other stuff between

IntegerProperty kingBonus = mainApp.getLocalModel().getMap().kingBonus();

kingBonus.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue.equals(0)) {
        kingRewardLabel.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        kingRewardLabel.setText(String.valueOf(newValue.intValue()));
    }
});

// testing the listener 
kingBonus.setValue(25);
```

I have already tried to debug a little but everything seems fine, no error, no exception thrown, just the listener does not work, or at least not as I expect, because the `Label` still show the default text "Label", instead of "25"

Comment: Seems to me like it should work. Are you sure this is indeed the same label? What happens is you add `kingRewardLabel.setText("Test")` after the last line?

Comment: @sillyfly i have tested the listener it works for value !=0 but not entering the listener when i setValue(0) why this is happening?

Comment: If the initial value is 0 then setting it to 0 won't trigger a change. Does it work if you set to to a value other than 0, then set to 0?

Comment: @sillyfly oh that's correct yes it works.I didn't though about that :)..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use simply [bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) to achieve this:

```
kingRewardLabel.textProperty().bind(kingBonus.asString());
kingRewardLabel.visibleProperty().bind(kingBonus.greaterThan(0));
```

The `Label` `kingRewardLabel` will display the value of the `IntegerProperty` `kingBonus` and it is only visible if the displayed value is greater than zero.

But, if you want to stay with listeners:

```
kingBonus.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    kingRewardLabel.setVisible(newVal.intValue() > 0);
    kingRewardLabel.setText(newVal.toString());
});
```

This is almost the same as your listener in the question, but in that case, if the `Label` became invisible, it will never become visible again as `kingRewardLabel.setVisible(true)` is never called.

Finally, to answer your question about why the listener is "not working" - there can be two possible reasons:

**1)** The `Label`, which one is displayed is not the `Label` stored in `kingRewardLabel`

**2)** At the time when you call `kingBonus.setValue(25);`, the value stored in `kingBonus` is already 25, no changed event will be fired, therefore the listener is not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this:

```
 kingBonus.addListener(l -> {
            int value = kingBonus.getValue().intValue();
            System.out.println("Entered listener for value:" + value);
            if (value == 0)
                kingRewardLabel.setVisible(false);
            else
                kingRewardLabel.setText(value+"");  
        });
    });
```